# Using another mailserver and domain because of spam status

Tags: domain, hosting, spam, email-server

A customer (customer.com) kind of abused a mailing service (iContact) by sending to much promotions. They used their main email as sender (info@costumer.com). Because of that action, hotmail banned all incoming email from @costumer.com

I'm the developer of their website, and now i have this issue: When someone creates an account, he/she receives an activation email before he/she can start using the service. When a new user tries to register with a hotmail account, he/she never receives the activation link.

I proposed to buy a new domain called customersomething.com, and setup a mailserver for that domain, so that any email sent from the customer.com site, uses info@customersomething.com as sender through customersomething.com mailserver.

So my questions are:

1. am I focusing the right approach?
2. where can I acquire a domain with a mailserver service only? (since they don't really need a complete hosting service)

Of course, I'll be noticing them that they cannot under any circumstances use the new info@customersomething.com as sender for their mailing service with iContact.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "am I focusing the right approach?" No you're not. The right approach is to fix the problem. Have your client contact Hotmail and find out what they need to do to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`am I focusing the right approach?`- technically you should be working with the customer to make sure they aren't abusing their email services.

Here's my advice:

1. Start here: http://mail.live.com/mail/policies.aspx ...make sure the customer knows as well how to make sure their email isn't abusing Hotmail/Outlook.com's policies.  The same would go for whatever email you decide to setup separately (if you still go down that path)
2. Get with Hotmail support to remove from the blacklist: https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts&scrx=1
3. If you want to go down the path of using another domain for the email registrations, why not use/create one on whatever hosting provider is currently hosting the domain?  Adding another mail domain should be very cheap at that point and administered from the same control panels/admin pages as the current domain/site.  I would do something like a subdomain of sorts, like @web.customer.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sounds perfectly reasonable. Note that if you don't need to receive inbound messages on the new domain then you don't need to set up a mail server, as you'll be sending outbound through your existing setup.
2. Just register the domain name, you don't need a hosting package to send. Make sure you create a valid SPF record in your DNS (i.e., one that specifies your current app host as a valid sender for that domain) and you'll be able to send "From" the new domain right on your existing server.

Comment: But if Hotmail is also blocking the current webserver's IP address, the new domain's emails will still be blocked, right?

Comment: Possibly -- depends how they're blocking. Your post seemed to indicate they were blocking by domain not IP. If they're doing the latter as well, then yes, your concern is valid. However, even in this case, I wouldn't go so far as to set up a host just for email, I'd use a service like Mailgun or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> am I focusing the right approach?

yes, you can do it that way; but your could also check what is blocked by the rbl hotmail uses: either the current mailserver's ip (could be mitigated) or its domainname (bad -> leads to your approach)

tools to check for blacklist:

- [robtex.com](https://ip.robtex.com/8.8.8.8.html#blacklists) (example-ip 8.8.8.8)
- [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

if just the ip is "burned" your could probably switch to another mailprovider to get through, but YMMV, so your approach seems to be the cleanest.

> where can I acquire a domain with a mailserver service only? (since they don't really need a complete hosting service)

depends on where youre clients are located; in europe i'd suggest to take a look at [df.eu](http://www.df.eu/de/e-mail-hosting/); they have a good and reliable mailservice for small setups, ROW i dont know.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The customer is located in South America (Ecuador).

Comment: My customer site runs on belfast.servershost.net, and it is indeed in a few blacklists according to mxtoolbox. Since it is a shared hosting, it could've also been someone else's account fault.